# How can an Suggested Edit be Edited and Reject and Edited at the same time?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6063523) suggested edit. I clicked the `Improve Edit` button, and the OP clicked the `Reject and Edit` button. The result was that Community approved it:

[image]

How can this be? Why could the edit be approved and rejected "at the same time", and why was my action used and not the one of the OP?

Comment: @psubsee2003 But why could the OP then still click `Reject and Edit`? I often see those red boxes where it says that I can't review it anymore for ... reasons

Comment: @Msrdo tried to tie everything together with an answer.  Because this behavior is relatively new (the "Improve" and "Reject and Edit" are relatively new features - they are modifications of the previous implementation), I am only theorizing based on how the system worked in the old implementation.,

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm just curious why both of them could review, if the post was already reviewed I normally get notified of that

Answer (score 1):

Check the precise timestamps.

Your review:

> [image]

OP's review

> [image]

You clicked "Edit" 3 seconds before the OP clicked "Reject and Edit". The moment you clicked "Edit", the edit was approved, so anything that happened after that was irrelevant. The reason the OP's reject and edit was listed is likely because the OP was viewing the suggested edit the same time you did so the action was recorded, just didn't count for approval/rejection since you were faster.

It's a race condition.  You were both performing the same action as the same time (reviewing the suggested edit) and you just happened to be a little faster.

The timeline is roughly

1. You opened the suggested edit page and started reviewing
2. The OP saw the red notification and opened the suggested edit page and started reviewing
3. You completed your review and decided to click "Edit".  The moment you did that, the edit was approved, the editor received his +2 bonus.
4. The OP completed his/her review and decided to click "Reject and Edit".  Since you already approved the edit, the reject part of tjhe OP's review didn't count.

Where this really get confusing is **after** step 4.  The final revision theoretically should be depend greatly on how fast both you and the OP edited the post.  But looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26528225/revisions), it is unclear however if this is what happened.

Your improved edit was committed first, the OP then has an empty edit following yours.  It is possible that the OP made the same exact edit as yours so there were no changes, but in theory, if the OP made significant changes, their edit would have effectively rolled back the suggested edit and your edit, but it is not clear if this actually occured.

---

As for why this occurred, typically, once someone is actively reviewing the post (this goes for any review queue), the system does not prevent them from completing the review.  The system only prevents a user from entering the review after the review was already completed.  In my example timeline above, if Step 3 happened **before** Step 2, then the OP would not have been permitted to review the post because the review was completed.  That is why the order of the events is very important.

Comment: Disagreed. If I review, I sometimes see a little red box coming up that I can review the item anymore (normally with a reason).

Comment: @msrd0 please pay attention to what I am saying.  The user saw the notification you are talking about and entered the review **before** you clicked "Edit".  This means that the edit was still available for review and the system allowed the user to try to review the post.

Comment: No, I get those red boxes when I see the review, and then click one of the buttons, but the review was already done. I'm sure that they exist in the Low Quality Review Queue, and I thought I already got one in the Suggested Edits Review Queue too

Comment: @msrd0 Forgive my rather blunt comment, but you are still not paying attention to what I am saying.  Read the timeline again.  This has absolutely nothing to do with the notification.  When the OP started to review the post (and was looking the same suggested edit page you were), you were not done reviewing the post, so the review was still available.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that the OP gets an error if he clicks on any button (in this example Reject and Edit) that says him that he isn't allowed to review this suggested edit anymore

Comment: The system doesn't block the review, it blocks accessing the review.  Once the OP was viewing the suggested edit, he was allowed to complete the review regardless of what you did.  But your actions, since they were completed first, took priority.